# Flutter error assets : EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE

Tags: flutter, dart

The image is not displayed, like all the paths are correctly set.
You can see the code.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you added images when your app was running and you did hot reload then may also this occur. i suggest you to stop app and do flutter clean and run you app again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because of indentation. Try using a reformat of pubspec file and it will work perfectly.
Try like below **Example:**

```
name: my_flutter_app
description: A new Flutter application.

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true,
  assets:
    - assets/images/icon1.png
    - assets/images/icon2.png
    - assets/images/icon3.png
    - assets/images/icon4.png
    - assets/images/icon5.png
```

*dash (-) of image must be below the second 's' of assets.

Comment: @АкбарСулаймонов your welcome. kindly accept the answer by clicking right arrow to let other know about the solution. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because your indentation in the `pubspec.yalm` file is wrong.

Try correcting the indentation. Use the code below:
It works perfectly fine.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/icon1.png
    - assets/images/icon2.png
    - assets/images/icon3.png
    - assets/images/icon4.png
    - assets/images/icon5.png
```

I hope this helps